# How to optimize this 2 lines of bash code

Tags: linux, bash, command

I want to optimize a bash code using 1 line instead of two
this is the lines i want to optimize:

```
grep -E "$name" /etc/passwd
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
     #...
```

so the if will test the exit of the last command (grep), i want to merge "grep -E "$name" /etc/passwd" in the if statement to have something like:

```
if [ ##### -eq 0 ]
```

thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the exit code of the command directly in the if statement:

```
if grep .... 
then
  echo "found"
else
  echo "not found"
fi
```

If you want to silence the output of the grep command you can add the `-q` option, and if you want to quit after the first match (saves time on large files) you can use  `-m 1`.

Answer (score 3):

Without *if*:

```
grep "name" file && do_something
```